Что означает константа кнопки 262192 в функции MsgBox?
Чтобы вывести сообщение через командную строку, можно создать .vbs файл с функцией MsgBox
(echo MsgBox "Line 1" ^& vbCrLf ^& "Line 2", 262192, "Title") > popup.vbs

Откуда взялась константа 262192? Получается иконка предупреждения со звуков и кнопка Ок, но в официальной справке написано, что можно просто использовать vbExclamation - 48. Так откуда же взялось 262192?

262192 = 262144 + 32 + 16, про 32 и 16 в справке написано, а про 262144 видимо придётся смотреть MB_TOPMOST вот тут https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-messagebox

Это константы "MB_xx", и расшифровываются они так:
262192 = 40030h 
--------------------------
MB_TOPMOST       = 040000h
MB_ICONQUESTION  = 000020h
MB_ICONHAND      = 000010h

или...
MB_ICONEXCLAMATION  = 000030h

